# Maven Failsafe: Exclude tests which are part of a test suite

Tags: maven, unit-testing, integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm using Maven Failsafe to execute integration tests in my project. Therefore I include a class which uses the JUnit Suite feature.

Is it possible to exclude tests, which are included in the test suite, through the `<excludes>`?

Until now I tried to exclude them in that way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Some config done here -->
                <includes>
                    <include>com.package.TestSuiteToInclude</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>com.package.TestToExclude</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But this did not work.
I would prefer to exclude them in the pom.xml rather than creating and maintaining another test suite without them.

Comment: first remove the provider you have added manually let failsafe doing that...furthermore I strongly recommend to get rid of a test suite and better use naming conventions for integration like `*IT.java` which is supported by default by failsafe-plugin....